# Build.VERSION.base_os returns empty string on Android 8

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I've tested this on 3 Samsung devices, 1 phone has Android 6 which does return the base_os and 2 devices (1 phone, 1 tablet) on Android 8 that returns an empty string. The two devices however do return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT with the value 26.

Comment: Those two devices, are they samsungs?

Comment: Yes all three devices are Samsung. The one working is SAMSUNG-SM-G930A - 6.0.1 (phone). The two not working are SM-T820 - 8.0.0 (which is a tablet) and SM-G930U - 8.0.0 (phone). Since the two not working are running on 8.0.0 that is why I am suspecting it is the issue.

Comment: Asus Zenfone 5Z with Android 9 also returns empty Build.VERSION.BASE_OS